# ColdFusion: How to bind the @change of an element (cfselect) to a cffunction?

Tags: coldfusion, bind, cfselect

I'm trying to bind the following code to a cfselect, and call a cffunction within a cfc.

```
<cfset qry_student = #getUsersForMassEmail('S',session.termcode,{cmbCRN@change})#>
```

My problem is with `{cmbCRN@change}`, which is giving me the following output:

> Invalid construct: Either argument or name is missing.

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: For starters..stop using `cfselect` and any other UI elements that are part of ColdFusion. They are poorly implemented and limited in functionality. Use plain old `select` and a JavaScript library such as jQuery to learn how to do it the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your participation Matt and Scott. My problem is with the token @change. "Invalid token @". That's what I'm looking for, to use the token within the function. Right now I'm working to retrieve the data with cfml2js, however, I would like to know the correct way to use the token.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, using cfselect and bindings like this is not recommended, but, I'll answer anyway. The binding for CF UI stuff are for *client* side code. Ie, I can specify a UI item and say, when another UI item changes, change me too. You are trying to bind to a cfselect from a local variable. If you think about it, that variable won't exist in the client side code - it is just CF code. You just can't do that.

Comment: Thanks Raymond for your advise. 

Let's switch to a select then. Do you have a reference where I can take a look to bind a select to a cffunction instead? (I'm aware about the client/server interaction), and for that reason I'm coding with cfml2js. Resume: I have a select, when a change occur within the select, it has to call the cffunction. Thanks again.

Comment: You can run JS code when the cfselect changes, and *that* JS code can call a CFC. Look at the docs for cfajaxproxy for an example.

Comment: But to be clear, if you have just begun this work, I urge you to stop. http://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/